# Element created with document.createElement inside an if Condition not recognized outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to use createElement inside an if statement but it just doesn't work. The `headerLink` is not recognized outside of the if statement.

Can someone explain what's missing?

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Declaring `headerLink` outside the if statement. This doesn't work
2. If I move the `appendChild` and `removeChild` inside the if statement, it starts to work. But, that would result in duplicate code since I will need to copy the same inside the else statement

   ```
   React.useEffect(() => {
       const head = document.head;
       const scriptType = "text/css";


       if (scriptType === "text/css") {
           const headerLink = document.createElement( "link" );
       } else {
           const headerLink = document.createElement( "script" ); 
       }


       // this line doesn't work - headerLink is not recognized
       head.appendChild(headerLink);

       return () => {  
           // this line doesn't work - again, headerLink is not recognized
           head.removeChild(headerLink);
       };
   }, []);
   ```

Comment: const is block scoped. You define it in a block and try to use outside

Comment: what would be the alternative? I tried `let` and that also didn't work

Comment: let us also block scoped. var isn't

Comment: You need to declare the variable outside of the if/else blocks, otherwise it isn't visible to subsequent statements. Worth brushing up on [MDN how to use const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Comment: I would suggest declaring something like let myElement  = "link" and using an if block to change it if necessary, then creating the element

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You probably shouldn't be using native DOM methods with React in that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the declaration of the `headerLink` outside the `if` clause. But you will have to use `let` in that case.

```
let headerLink;

if (scriptType === "text/css") {
    headerLink = document.createElement( "link" );
} else {
    headerLink = document.createElement( "script" ); 
}
```

Or you can use ternary conditional operator to create element

```
const headerLink = document.createElement( scriptType === "text/css" ? "link" : "script" );
```

Comment: Do you think this is a reasonable approach for React?

Comment: I agree with your comment above that DOM should not be manipulated if using React. But the above question had limited context and it specifically asked about the DOM.

Comment: The context it's being used in a `useEffect`. The code doesn't make any sense. `scriptType` will always be `"text/css"`. It answers one question, but doesn't resolve all the other ones.

Comment: thanks, yes I used let and it worked. Only thing I was missing were the types. Posting that version below

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Aditya's answer and Sandil's comment above, resolved the issue

```
useEffect(() => {

        const head = document.head;

        let headerScript: HTMLLinkElement | HTMLScriptElement;

 

        if(scriptType === "text/css") {

            headerScript = document.createElement( "link" );

        } else {

            headerScript = document.createElement( "script" );

        }

        head.appendChild(headerScript);

 

        return () => {

            head.removeChild(headerScript);

        };

       

        

    }, []);
```